# Splitting formatted output to multiple lines in a controlled fashion

Tags: formatting, boxes

Let's consider a slightly complicated expression in `TraditionalForm`:

```
Reduce[#, Backsubstitution -> True] & /@ 
  BooleanMinimize@
   CylindricalDecomposition[
    x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && y <= x, {x, y}] // TraditionalForm
```

> $(y=0\land x=1)\lor
>    \left(y=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\land
>    x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\lor
>    \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<x\leq
>    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\land
>    -\sqrt{1-x^2}\leq y\leq
>    x\right)\lor
>    \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<x<1\land -\sqrt{1-x^2}\leq y\leq
>    \sqrt{1-x^2}\right)$

My question is: How do I split this result for improved readability so that each subexpression of this disjunctive normal form expression is on its own line, and $\lor$ ends the line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
exp = Reduce[#, Backsubstitution -> True] & /@ 
   BooleanMinimize@ CylindricalDecomposition[x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && y <= x, {x, y}];

ToBoxes[TraditionalForm @ exp] /. "\[Or]" -> "\[Or]\n" // RawBoxes
```

> [image]

Or, wrap with `TraditionalForm`:

```
ToBoxes[TraditionalForm@exp] /. "\[Or]" -> "\[Or]\n" // RawBoxes // TraditionalForm
```

> [image]

Original size of $\lor$s can be retained by replacing them with a separate $\lor$ and a newline:

```
ToBoxes[TraditionalForm@exp] /.
  "\[Or]" -> Sequence["\[Or]", "\n"] // RawBoxes // TraditionalForm
```

> [image]

Comment: Even better if you add `// TraditionalForm` in the end. Size of $\lor$s seems to change, though. That would be fixed with `"\[Or]" -> Sequence["\[Or]", "\n"]`

Comment: @kirma, updated with the suggested change.